# how to show reflection of a different object in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

I have a mirror and an object in front of it. I want to hide the reflection of that object and show instead a reflection in the mirror of another object hidden in that scene,is that possible?

[image]

Comment: A different object altogether, or the same object with a different material?

Comment: a different object, the sketch is just to show what i mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I slapped together a quick example. In short - 
The visibility options for the first object (Suzanne) have glossy, shadow and diffuse turned off.

[image]

The second object (cone) has only visibility for glossy enabled.

[image]

This results in Suzanne not being visible in the reflection and the cone just being visible in the mirror.

[image]

Depending on what you're needing, there might be more involved ways of doing it via compositing, but I hope this answers your original question.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Also is there a way to have the suzanne head show its reflection on everything except the mirror?

Comment: Only if you do it via compositing/render layers, not with this general approach unfortunately

Comment: because my idea was to have a very shiny floor material like it's wet. I can change it to a rough surface like rock but it would be useful to know also for future projects if someone knows how to do it.

Comment: oh ok unluckily i don't know how to use the compositor and render layers very well yet.. thanks for the answers!!