# Objects reflected in a mirror only

Tags: rendering, export, mirror

I want to make a mirror and but hide the room around it that it reflects.

But I want this as a 3D model (not for a render or a video)...

Not as easy as it seems. Any ideas?
Thanks
B

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Like if you have a cube in a middle of a room in front of mirror - so in the mirror is reflected cube but not the room environment. What would be surround instead of a room reflection?

Comment: if your using eevee you can use a reflection probe and bake it but do not enable auto bake and then hide the room, not sure if that is what you mean but i think it is

Comment: In cycles, this is very easy with object visibility settings.

Comment: @R-800 I have been following this thread (and the downloaded Blender file: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162839/how-to-show-reflection-of-a-different-object-in-cycles )
Which seems to work but when I export it to a .glTF or a .glb 3D file, I see the opposite : The mirror reflects the background HDRI image but not the objects. Where as I want to hide everything but the mirror & its reflections

Comment: @J Block, nothing is visible except the mirror (and the objects it reflecting). When you look at it as a 3D model in a .glTf / .glb viewer you can rotate around the mirror and see what the mirror is reflecting

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard, Thanks, but I am exporting the model and not rendering the image. Are you suggesting that I could bake a mirror texture in Cycles and then Hide the Objects the Outliner?

Comment: Thanks @ZargulTheWizard, it seems like this would be a valuable, I hope to get to the bottom of it...

Comment: What are you intending to import to? That might help

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard, Thanks. I'm trying to Export to a 3D model (probably .glTF or .glb maybe FBX) so that it can be seen in a Web viewer like Sketchfab

Comment: Ahh. Well, i’m not sure if what you’re wanting to do is possible, unfortunately. You might contact the sketchfab team, however. They have pretty good customer service. :-)

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thanks, I appreciate... Will keep trying.